# import error in terminal but works in Pycharm

Tags: macos, python-3.x, terminal, pycharm

I have a file structure just like
[image]

I can run code using Pycharm, but when copy all project to Ubuntu Server and run RunCNN2.py with "**python3 sample/classifier/RunCNN2.py**"using terminal, it shows information below

***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample/classifier/RunCNN2.py", line 12, in 
    from sample.parameters.Parameter import parameters
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'***

line 12 is "**from sample.parameters.Parameter import parameters**"

and **init**.py in classifier folder is

**__all__ = ["RunCNN", "RunCNN2"]**

**init**.py in parameters folder is

**__all__ = ["ClassDefination", "Parameter"]**

and **init**.py in sample folder is **empty**

so, I wonder why it doesn't works in terminal??